# Thumb color of slider becomes grey

Tags: vuetify.js

Sometimes the thumb color of the v-slider component becomes grey. Even when the value is correct and is correctly displayed in the middle of the range.

Why is this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use always-dirty to avoid this.